# PHP code missing in Wordpress HTML Editor

Tags: php, wordpress

I put some PHP Code in one of my page after I install a PHP Plugin (Name : PHP Execution), It is working well in HTML Editor view, but when I change the view to Visual Editor, it is missing from the HTML Editor and also from the real content. Can anybody help me...

Comment: Sounds like you haven't enabled PHP execution in main page content.

Comment: Allowing people to put PHP code into your application is an incredibly bad idea.

Comment: In most cases it is a desing error if you need to put php code, that will be executed, in the post content!

Answer (score 4):

Try using http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/exec-php/

Also, one more plugin with details helps you can found here... http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/execute-php-in-wordpress-post-page-and-widget-sidebar/